# Integer part hack fro the Fast inverse square root

Tags: python, c++, performance

Can someone explain the meaning of this line of code?

```
i  = * ( long * ) &y;
```

The code is from wikipedia, [Fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code).
Is there a way to do the same with python?

Comment: `&y` is casted to a `long*` pointer and dereferenced. The result is stored in `i`. I doub't to do such is possible in python.

Comment: You could possibly achieve the same using the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html): `i = struct.unpack('l', struct.pack('f', y))`, but the actual line relies on how the values are represented in memory - which isn't something you can easily get at with python.

Answer (score 0):

In Python why not just do `x**-1/2` or `x**-.5`